# Is it possible to reach lower temperatures than the Boyle temperature in de van der Waals equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, order-of-magnitude

We know that for a real gas we can write a virial expansion in powers of $p$:

$$pV=Nk_{B}T+B(T)p+\cdots$$

It results that the van der Waals equation:

$$\left[p+a\left(\frac{N}{V}\right)^{2}\right]\left(V-Nb\right)=Nk_{B}T$$

can be rewritten like

$$pV=Nk_{B}T+\frac{N}{N_{A}}\left(b-\frac{a}{k_{B}T}\right)p+\cdots$$

My **question** is: can the factor $\left(b-\frac{a}{k_{B}T}\right)$ change of sign?

I know that the [Boyle temperature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyle_temperature) makes zero this factor. That makes me think that lower temperatures make the factor change of sign.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, $b$ is roughly the volume of a molecule, and $a$ is enhanced by a factor of $\frac{1}{k_{b}}$... but I don't know if $a$ is abnormally small.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer I changed my original question. I wasn't being concise. Can you review it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at the so called Boyle Temperature, your gas behaves like an ideal gas. That means that the modifications induced to the virial equation by the factors $b$ and $a$ balance out. I am sure you know what the factors $a$ and $b$ represent *****.

Below and above that temperature, they don't cancel out. Therefore, the gas does not behave ideally. There is nothing ***interesting or significant*** about the factor changing sign because, its supposed to. You can try and plot this function for fixed $p$ or $v$ as a fucntion of $T$ and also plot the ideal gas law for fixed $p$ or $v$ and you will see that  the point where they intersect is the Boyle Temperature.

***$a$** is a measure for the attraction between the particles, and **$b$** is the average volume excluded from v by a particle.